# Centralizing container div on the page - Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having problems when centering the page because centralize both sides has been made since added several classes and attributes in the tag style but got no success, and to better exemplify the incident removed a print and place mushrooms but show the difference between the top and bottom.
`head` code:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../FullPage/jquery.fullPage.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../FullPage/vendors/jquery.easings.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../FullPage/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
</head>
```

Code with Bootstrap 3.3.1:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> 
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button> 
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Meu Site</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Create Account</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <div class="container span7 text-center col-md-4 col-md-offset-3" style="margin: 0 auto;float: none; border: 3px solid red">
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <img src="../../app.images/logo.jpg" />
            </div>
            <form style="border:3px solid blue" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Opt1</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" checked="">Opt2</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Opt3</label>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info input-group-btn" style="font-size:14px">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                    </a>
                    <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Search" />
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div style="border:3px solid yellow">
                Slogan
            </div>
            <div style="border:3px solid green">
                <a href="#">Mobile</a>
                <a href="#">Addons</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Difference between the top and bottom:
[image]

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: thanks for answer me, I create a css file and link the html file to css file, however it did not work

Comment: You have to show your effort on what did not work. Bootstrap has no vertical-align:middle of their content unless you do the custom css and wrappers and other workarounds. Use one of the methods out there in the wild, then post that effort. It may require stripping, over-riding and various other CSS techniques.